# react show unique name data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render

i am facing an issue in react js. i want to display `unique name` in component page .

react component

```
    this.state = { 
      staff: [],
    }


  //fetch appointment data
  componentDidMount() {
     axios.get(`http://localhost/v1/appointments/`)
    .then(res => {
      // console.log(res);
      const appointmentdata = res.data; 
        this.setState({ 
          staff : appointmentdata.staff
        });
      })
    }



    <div className="row">
          {this.state.staff.map((data, i) => (
          <div className="full-block">
              <p key={i}>
              {data.full_name}
              </p></div>
          )
          )}
  </div>
```

My Output

```
shop
shop
Staff
Staff
book
```

expected output: display unique name from data

```
shop
Staff
book
```

what should i change in my do? anyone help me?

Comment: First of all, add the key property to the div, not the p.

Answer (score 0):

You can check something like https://lodash.com/docs/#uniq to have a duplication free Array. Then you just map it like you're doing.

```
_.uniq(this.state.staff).map((data, i) => (
          <div className="full-block">
            <p key={i}>
              {data.full_name}
            </p>
          </div>
        )
      )
```

If you don't want to use an external library you can also check [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and play around with it. You would probably need to convert it back to an Array as a Set doesn't have a `map` method.

One possible solution using Set would be this:

```
const mySet = new Set(this.state.staff)
const staffArray = Array.from(mySet)

staffArray.map((data, i) => (
      <div className="full-block">
        <p key={i}>
          {data.full_name}
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  )
```

Comment: how i do in my code ? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13058340/pedro-filipe)

Comment: can make the simple logic ? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13058340/pedro-filipe)

Comment: I added an example using lodash

Comment: `_.uniq({data.full_name})` i added in my code [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13058340/pedro-filipe)

Comment: '_' is not defined  no-undef `Error`

Comment: You need to install lodash using NPM and import it just like you import React.